# Suppose $K$ is a field such that every finite Galois extension of $K$ is cyclic. Is there a name for this property?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

Let $K$ be a field such that the following property is satisfied: every finite Galois extension of $K$ is cyclic. Is there a name for this kind of fields or this property? I haven’t been able to find anything online.

Also, could someone give me an example of such kind of fields?

Comment: $Gal(K^{sep}/K)$ is a quotient of $\varprojlim \Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$, ie. $K=(K^{sep})^\sigma$ for some automorphism of $K^{sep}$ such that $\langle \sigma \rangle a$ is finite for all $a\in K^{sep}$.

Comment: Every finite field has this property :-)

Comment: $\mathbb R$ is certainly another example.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you are interested in this type of fields?

Comment: @KentaS I came across some exercises that involved proving properties for this particular type of fields and was trying to get some intuition for them